# Complicated phrase: "...tolerably accurately represented experience..."

Tags: adverbial-phrases

Can the bold phrase be restated like this: represented experience which is tolerably accurate? If yes, Which one is more usual? If not is there any more usual way to say that?

> Availability means confident expectation—gained from “**tolerably accurately” (p. 202) represented experience** over a significant time period—that the attachment figure will be available

Answer (score 3):

In this passage, "tolerably" is an adverb. According to the definition I learned as a kid, an adverb is a word that modifies a verb, adjective, or another adverb. In this case, "tolerably", an adverb, is modifying "accurately", also an adverb. In your suggestion, "tolerably", an adverb, is modifying "accurate", an adjective.

For

> Availability means confident expectation—gained from “tolerably accurately” (p. 202) represented experience over a significant time period—that the attachment figure will be available.

vs

> Availability means confident expectation—gained from represented experience which is “tolerably accurate” (p. 202) over a significant time period—that the attachment figure will be available.

I personally think that the second one (your suggestion) sounds better. ***However***, note that the author is quoting another passage in this point. It may be that the original author used "tolerably accurately" in their writing because it made more sense. Since this author is quoting them, it may be that this author wants to keep the original wording, so they structured the sentence you quoted in an odd way to preserve the original wording.

Comment: I think your last paragraph explanation is more realistic.

Answer (score 1):

The experience is represented tolerably accurately.

Improvements:

The experience is represented with tolerable accuracy.

The representation of the experience is tolerably accurate.

Your suggestion:

...represented experience which is tolerably accurate

is not appropriate because it is the representation of the experience, not the experience *per se*, which is accurate.  Experience cannot be accurate or inaccurate.

Comment: How would this address the fact that it is being quoted/cited?

Comment: @Stephen S: I upvoted your answer because your suggestion that the desire to quote verbatim is what led to the awkwardness of "tolerably accurately represented experience".  But the point I'm making is that OP's rewording is not an improvement because his *which*-clause modifies "experience" when it is the representation that is to some degree accurate..